# custom font in laravel 5.2 email using aws

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, html-email, amazon-ses

Hi I want to import custom font(open sans) in my email that is sending through laravel 5.2 using amazon. I am using css import it works only on some platforms like ios and other email clients. It doesn't works in gmail. Please give provide solution for this problem.

Comment: Use images instead of text - that is the only solution i am aware of currently. If you dont want images, design the email to dispaly well with a universal (eg 'websafe') font

Comment: Hi @Steve Thanks for your answer but i don't want to use image. my requirement is only open sans

Comment: Then im afraid your task is impossible - gmail (and other email clients) does not load external fonts, so if the user doesnt have the font installed, it wont work. Go look through your own emails - especially from big companies. Text will be arial/helvetica/verdana (or another standard websafe font). Anything non standard will be images

Comment: Ok thank you @Steve for your clarification. I will try to use web fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`@font-face` is not supported in all email clients**](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/).

Many email clients do not support custom fonts and use system fonts instead. It has nothing to do with laravel or amazon.

iOS *does* support web fonts, so it displays Open Sans when specified. Unfortunately Gmail *does not* support web fonts, so it skips over Open Sans and displays the first system font it finds in the font stack. Outside of using an image (which I don't recommend either!) there's currently no way to display Open Sans in Gmail.

[More info on email typography, web fonts, and fallbacks](https://litmus.com/blog/typography-tips-for-email-designers).

Comment: thank you @Ted Goas with clean and clear information.